Knowing that the area of a lateral face is equal to the area of the base, find the measure of the angle formed by the planes $(MBN)$ and $(ABC)$.
the question
Let $VABCD$ be a regular quadrilateral pyramid, $M$ the midpoint of the edge $VC$, $N$ the midpoint of the edge $AD$. Knowing that the area of a lateral face is equal to the area of the base, find the measure of the angle formed by the planes $(MBN)$ and $(ABC)$.
The idea
drawing

As you can see in the drawing I let VO be the height of the pyramid and $X$ the intersection of AC and BN.
First of all, we must determine the intersection of planes $(MBN)$ and $(ABC)$, which is $BN$.
We now have to take some perpendiculars that are included in those planes on $BN$ and they would make the angle we search for.
we know that $A(VAD)=A(ABCD)=\frac{VN*AD}{2}=AD*BC$, which makes $VN=2AD=2AB$
by the theorem of the midline we get that $NO=\frac{AB}{2}$
Also I let that point x because I thought it will help us with some sides by doing some similarity.
I don't know what to do forward. Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Hint (almost solution).
First solution. One way to solve this problem without thinking too much, just doing calculations, is to apply the orthogonal projection theorem.

When orthogonally projected onto a plane $(ABC)$, triangle $MNB$ transforms into triangle $ENB$. Therefore the following formula is valid:
$$S_{\triangle ENB} = S_{\triangle MNB} \cdot \cos \varphi,$$
where $\varphi$ is the angle between planes $(MNB)$ and $(ENB)$. Now let’s just calculate the areas of the triangles $MNB$ and $ENB$. Let $AB = a$, then we can express the lengths of the segments $NE$ and $BE$ using the following picture:

From the similarity of triangles $CE'E$ and $CDA$ we get that $\frac{E'C}{DC} = \frac{E'E}{DA} = \frac{EC}{AC} = \frac{1}{4}$. Hence, $E'C = \frac{a}{4}$, $DE' = \frac{3a}{4}$, $E'E = \frac{a}{4}$. Using a trapezoid $DE'EN$, we get that $NE = \sqrt{(a/2 - a/4)^2 + (3a/4)^2} = \sqrt{10}a/4$. From triangle $BOE$ we get that $BE = \sqrt{(\sqrt{2}a/4)^2 + (\sqrt{2}a/2)^2}  = \sqrt{10}a/4$. From triangle $BAN$ we get that $BN = \sqrt{a^2 + a^2 /4 } = \sqrt{5}a/2$. Now we know the lengths of all sides of the triangle $ENB$ and therefore we can find $S_{\triangle ENB}$.
Now let's find the lengths of the sides $MN$ and $BM$ of the triangle $MNB$. From triangle $MEN$ we get that $MN = \sqrt{ME^2 + NE^2}$. We already know the length of the segment $NE$. The length of the segment $ME$ can be found using the fact that $ME$ is the midline of the triangle $VOC$ and therefore $ME = \frac{1}{2} VO$. The length of the height $VO$ of the pyramid can be found from right triangle $VOA$. In triangle $VOA$ we know the length of $OA$ and we can find the length of $VA$ from an isosceles triangle $VAB$, in which we know the length of the base $AB = a$ and the length of the height $VN = 2a$ drawn to the base. So we know how to find the length of $MN$. We can find the length of the segment $BM$ using the fact that this segment is the median in an isosceles triangle $VBC$ drawn to the lateral side $VC$. Now we know the lengths of all sides of the triangle $MNB$ and therefore we can find $S_{\triangle MNB}$.
Next, using the formula $ \cos \varphi = S_{\triangle ENB}/  S_{\triangle MNB} $, we find $\cos \varphi$.
It may not be the easiest way, but it works.
Second solution. Another way to solve this is note that $BE=EN$ and therefore $BM=MN$. So, both triangles $ENB$ and $MNB$ are isosceles. This means that the perpendicular to $BN$ in both triangles falls into the middle of segment $BN$. Let $K$ be the midpoint of the segment $BN$. Now we can consider right triangle $MKE$ and find angle $\varphi$ if we find the lengths of any two sides of this triangle. For example, we can find $ME$ from the first solution and we can find $EK$ from triangle $ENB$ if we know lengths of sides of this triangle. The first solution shows how this can be done.
